# Computer resets randomly?

Tags: memory, reboot, reset

I have recently upgraded my machine with another 8GB ram stick to 24GB.

However, ever since I have random poweroffs (no BSoD, nothing in error logs) followed by a regular boot.

They occur completely randomly, I can go days without one and other times I have three a day.

Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that the motherboard will handle 24GB of RAM?

Comment: @MikeNaylor The mainboard is specified to up to 32GB.

Comment: Can you provide a configuration of how the DIMMS are used and include speeds of the RAM in each slot?  Also are you using Channels with your RAM and was this installed in a pair?

Comment: I'm not sure this deserves down voting, but it is a little vague and possibly a duplicate. Cobra is more asking for things that could cause this, which would be a valid question. You may want to rephrase it.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Comment: Try the new RAM chips only to see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

Run [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) and test every bit of ram you have. It is probably a bad stick of ram. It also has the possibility of being a dying power supply or hard drive.

Check the most recently changed first! memtest will tell you what stick of memory is bad if there is one.

Upvoted the comment below and I'm adding it to the answer because it is very valid. BIOS will halt your PC if the temperature reaches unsafe levels.

Comment: Restarting could also be due to cpu being too hot, check the bios and check the temp while @ idle.